# error: invalid argument '-std=gnu99' not allowed with 'C++/ObjC++'

Tags: c++, c, macos, clang

I am trying to compile C library called [DevIL](http://openil.sourceforge.net/download.php) on OSX Maverick with Clang.I ran configure file then 'make' .I am getting the following error:

error: invalid argument '-std=gnu99' not allowed with 'C++/ObjC++'

Does it mean I am trying to compile C code with C++ compiler?How can I tell Clang to compile it as C lib?

Comment: Yeah, DevIL is a C++ library.

Comment: No it is not.It is C.Look at the source code.

Answer (score 1):

My standard answer to such problems is to use [MacPorts](http://macports.org). Once MacPorts is installed, it's as simple as:

```
 $ sudo port install libdevil
```

Comment: Event though your answer is useful the installation fails on XORG which also fails once  I try to install it via port  :)